# Right-to-Left Multicolumn text

Tags: adobe-indesign

I use Adobe InDesign 7. I have a two-column text frame. The direction of this two-columns text frame is left to right, but I need it the other way round. So I wonder how can I make its direction right to left?

I want to type Arabic text in this text frame. Since Arabic reads from right to left, I want InDesign to fill in the right-hand column first. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the story direction. The ME version has that control in the Story panel...